# Alternatives to dd to read/write to a disk?

Tags: performance, dd, cp, ssd, write

I'm using `cp` to read/write from an SSD drive but is not fast enough. Then I used `dd`, which is fast, especially with the drive unpartitioned. But I ran into errors like

> there is no space left on device

while I'm sure there is!

So, two questions, actually:

- Is it safe to use dd on an unpartitioned drive?
- Is there another alternative to read/ write large chunks of data?

I need to buffer some 400 blocks, 128 MB each. Data come in real-time and there is about 0.8 s to write each block.

**Some details about my system:**

- Hw/Sw: Zynq MPSoC FPGA with Linux built with Petalinux
- SSD model: ATP I-Temp 120 GB

No, it's not possible to pre-buffer in RAM (I wouldn't be here asking) as I only have 4 GB and the whole thing is 40-50 GB. I can only pre-buffer a few packages of 128 MB.

A single SSD for stream data: Completely agree, this is a preliminary demonstration. On a later stage, we will certainly have redundant reliable systems.

Comment: You probably want to include the actual commands that you are trying, along with mentioning what Unix you're using. Do this by updating your question (not in comments).  Since you are concerned about performance, adding some details about what brand of SSD you have may possibly be helpful (I don't know hardware though).

Comment: 1. Is it feasible for you to get enough RAM to buffer those 400 blocks, 128 MB each, which is 51.2 GB? 2. Yes, you can use `dd` to write on an unpartitioned drive. When I get 'there is no space left on device', it is a correct message. Could it ibe that some buffer gets choked in your case? 3. Have you considered an NVME drive, that should be faster than a standard SSD?

Comment: I don't think a single SSD is a good choice for a high volume constant data stream.  You would wear it out quite quickly.  You might want to consider RAID configuration or enterprise level SAN depending on what are you trying to achieve and what funds are available to you.

Comment: completely unclear where you are going with this. there's nothing about dd that makes it inherently faster than cp. add more context, commands, results. also specify hardware - some consumer SSDs have abysmal sustained write speeds.

Comment: `cp` and `dd` are tools for different use cases, they are not replacements for each other. To provide a useful answer you should read http://xyproblem.info/ first, then rewrite your question and tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: *No, it's not possible to pre-buffer in RAM*  From a business perspective, you're getting paid to write code to **hopefully** solve a problem that wouldn't be a problem if someone were willing to buy a bit of RAM. In that time, you're providing zero actual value.  It's also quite likely that it costs more to pay you to code around this issue than it would be to **just buy the RAM**.

Comment: Andrew Henle, could you come over here and tell us how to add 80 GB RAM to an FPGA? The good thing of living in the business models world is that real world constraints don't exist and nine women make a baby in a month, apparently.

Comment: Maybe `dd ... oflag=dsync` can solve the problems with buffer overflow (that may cause your 'there is no space left on device' messages). But you will have to check how it affects the write speed.